# InstallShield .NET 4 prerequisite failing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, installshield

I have created an InstallShield installer through visual studio 2010 which has the .NET 4 framework as a prerequisite.

During install some users are getting an error informing them that an error has occurred while downloading the .net installer.

I ran the installer with the debuglog command line argument and got the following:

```
7-24-2012[12:16:07 PM]: PrereqEngine: file,251743DFD3FDA414570524BAC9E55381,<ISProductFolder>\SetupPrerequisites\Microsoft .net\4.0\Full\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe,http://download.microsoft.com/downlo...ll_x86_x64.exe,,, -- Successful,
7-24-2012[12:16:07 PM]: PrereqEngine: execute,dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe,/q /norestart,/q /norestart,1641,3010,, -- Successful
7-24-2012[12:16:07 PM]: PrereqEngine: dependency,<ISProductFolder>\SetupPrerequisites\Windows Installer 3.1 (x86).prq, -- Successful
7-24-2012[12:16:07 PM]: PrereqEngine: dependency,<ISProductFolder>\SetupPrerequisites\Windows Imaging Component (x86).prq, -- Successful
7-24-2012[12:16:07 PM]: PrereqEngine: dependency,<ISProductFolder>\SetupPrerequisites\Windows Installer 3.1 for Windows Server 2003 SP1 (x86).prq, -- Successful
7-24-2012[12:16:07 PM]: PrereqEngine: dependency,<ISProductFolder>\SetupPrerequisites\Windows Imaging Component (x64).prq, -- Successful
7-24-2012[12:16:07 PM]: PrereqEngine: dependency,<ISProductFolder>\SetupPrerequisites\Windows Installer 3.1 for Windows Server 2003 SP1 (IA64).prq, -- Successful
7-24-2012[12:16:07 PM]: PrereqEngine: dependency,<ISProductFolder>\SetupPrerequisites\Windows Installer 3.1 for Windows Server 2003 SP1 (x64).prq, -- Successful
7-24-2012[12:16:07 PM]: PrereqEngine: dependency,<ISProductFolder>\SetupPrerequisites\Windows Installer 3.1 for Windows XP (x64).prq, -- Successful
7-24-2012[12:16:07 PM]: PrereqEngine: Id,{32D7E3D1-C9DF-4FA6-9F9B-4D5117AB2917},http://saturn.installshield.com/is/p...ites/microsoft .net framework 4.0 full.prq, -- Successful
7-24-2012[12:16:07 PM]: PrereqEngine: behavior,Optional,,Reboot,2,Failure,
7-24-2012[12:16:07 PM]: PrereqEngine: Lua,
7-24-2012[12:16:07 PM]: PrereqEngine: Hidden,
7-24-2012[12:16:07 PM]: PrereqEngine: MsiProgress,
7-24-2012[12:16:26 PM]: DownloadFiles: An error occurred while downloading the file http://download.microsoft.com/downlo...ll_x86_x64.exe. What would you like to do?
7-24-2012[12:16:30 PM]: Prerequisites returning 2
```

If I open internet explorer on the same computer and paste in the url to the .net installer from that log file it downloads without issue.

Any ideas on possible causes or steps to further investigate?

Comment: The computer I generated the log file on is running Windows 7

Comment: What's the MD5SUM of the file you can successfully download? If it's not 251743DFD3FDA414570524BAC9E55381, the .prq file may be outdated.

Comment: What's with the dots in the URLs?  Did you add them?

Comment: @Michael I got the user to download the file and generate file and it gave: 251743dfd3fda414570524bac9e55381 so that part looks fine

Comment: @HansPassant sorry about the urls they got truncated when i copied them. Here is the full link http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/A/95A9616B-7A37-4AF6-BC36-D6EA96C8DAAE/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe

Comment: Well, thanks for reminding me to steer clear from IS again.  Not logging an error number is pretty criminal.

Answer (score 0):

Can you repro on another machine? On another network?  Can you host the file on your own servers and update the URL in the PRQ?

You might need to put in a support request for this one.   This is my concern with "web" downloaders.  You optimze the user experience in one way at the risk of injecting external failure points.

Comment: Would prefer not to host the prerequisites on our servers as the installer is used by internal and external users. Problem only seems to affect specific internal users. Will gain access to one of the troubled machines tomorrow to further investigate.

Comment: Issue looks like it is caused by an authenticated proxy server. If I switch the machine to use a non authenticated proxy the download succeeds. Not sure why this is happening as the authentication should be transparent. Looks like I'll have to pass this issue on to the IT department.

Comment: I work for a Fortune 50 company and I've seen wierd things like this.  On one of my networks the silverlight redist downloads and is corrupted.  It works from other networks so it's like there is something corrupt stuck in the cache on one of the blue coat proxies.